# danielgindi/iOSCharts library : x axis label in horizontal bar chart

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

[image: Image with following Code with SetLabel Count]

with the following code

```
barchart.xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.white

barchart.xAxis.labelPosition = .topInside

barChart.xAxis.setLabelCount(7, force: true)
```

**Issue**: x axis grid get destructed 
[image: Image with following Code without setLabelCount]

```
barchart.xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.white

barchart.xAxis.labelPosition = .topInside
```

**Issue**: Right side Label gets hidden

**Solution Required**:
Need Following to be fixed:

*Grid should be aligned

*Label should be viewed

my code is :

```
barChart.legend.enabled = false

barChart.xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.white
barChart.xAxis.labelPosition = .topInside

barChart.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
barChart.leftAxis.enabled = true
barChart.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
barChart.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false

barChart.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
barChart.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
barChart.rightAxis.labelFont =  NSUIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13.0)
barChart.xAxis.labelFont = NSUIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
barChart.rightAxis.labelTextColor =  UIColor.white

barChart.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
barChart.rightAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
barChart.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i),yValues: [values[i]])
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }
   let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "HB2")
    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
    chartData.setValueFormatter(DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: formatter))
    barChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:dataPoints)
    barChart.data = chartData
```

Comment: please post chart setup code so can get idea whats going wrong with your code.

Comment: Please check my code @CodeChanger

Answer (score 0):

First of all label position should be `barchart.xAxis.labelPosition = .top` and I do not understand why grids are not aligned but if you use following code it should be right aligned it worked for me.
        chartView.legend.enabled = false

```
   // chartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.white
    chartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .top

    chartView.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
    chartView.leftAxis.enabled = true
    chartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    chartView.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false

    chartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
    chartView.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
    chartView.rightAxis.labelFont =  NSUIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13.0)
    chartView.xAxis.labelFont = NSUIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
    chartView.rightAxis.labelTextColor =  UIColor.white

    chartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
    chartView.rightAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
    chartView.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<unitsSold.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i),yValues: [unitsSold[i]])
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }
    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "HB2")
    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
    chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: months)
    chartView.data = chartData

    chartView.animate(yAxisDuration: 2.5)
```

I have removed your first formatter I do not understand why you used it but it gave me following chart.

[image: Horizontal bar chart]

Comment: thanks for the response.. one more issue that right side  label should be inside the graph.and that grid alignment is still have an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, see my graph that grid lines are boxed with horizontal graph, and right axis label are inside the grid, your solution its outside the grid and horizontal graph lines shows middle of the graph

Comment: @Marios actually I could not understand what is your problem and what do you need for alignment if you have any picture of what you need it could be helpful.

Comment: @atalayasa, could you please tell which property is for showing value at the top bar ? I used your code and tried, but all good other than those labels on top of the Bar.

Comment: @yogi it's been very long time since i do not deal with charts. However when you add `BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i),yValues: [unitsSold[i]])` `yValues` needs to be worked. Are you sure `yValues` is not empty?

Comment: @atalayasa, Hey I got it, chartData.setDrawValues(true) worked for me with current code i have implemented. But thanks for post overall.

Answer (score 0):

as per my exprience you need to add **lableCount** in your chart configuration like below so that it will calculate proper **xAxis** and show it on your chart

```
horiBarChartView.xAxis.labelCount = <yourXAxisArray>.count
```

If we are not setting this count some time it will not able to generate proper **xAxis** position on chart.

So try this once and let me know its working or not.

Comment: This solved only one problem boss.. grid line make the problem in alignment.

Comment: its totally depend on view size and we can't control it and if you check it properly that last line of chart and chart border messing this and that not  make any issue as its default.